# Attaching Air Compressor To Junction Box

Tags: electrical, wiring, garage, junction-box, compressor

I have a 4 inch metal junction box with a 3/4" mud ring attached and recessed into the drywall in my garage. I want to connect an air compressor to this junction box directly without using a plug. What do I need in order to close up the junction box and have a hole for a 3/4" flexible conduit to run to the compressor?

Is it as simple as buying a blank metal 2-gang cover plate and drilling a hole in it? Is there something off the shelf that's actually made for this?

Comment: Don't. Wire in an outlet box and plug the compressor into that.

Comment: If the compressor is direct wired, it means (in most jurisdictions) that you cannot take it when you move.  A plug and outlet is a little more expensive to install, but it adds serviceability, modularity, and you can easily move the compressor to a job site.  If the compressor has no cord, just install a pigtail (as for a range or electric dryer) if it is 240 volt, or a standard cord for 120 volt.

Comment: The problem I'm finding with the plugs is that the highest rated one I can find is for 3 HP and this particular compress is 5 HP. I thought hard-wiring it was the only "legal" way to do it.

Comment: @wallyK - if you disconnect it before the house is shown, (when selling) that should resolve that. John Hodge - a real 5HP or a marketing department's imagined 5 HP? Voltage and current from the nameplate?

Comment: If the compressor has a plug, it can be plugged in; you just need to be sure the circuit is rated to handle it. 5HP is 2739 watts; at 120 volts that's 22 amps, at 240V it's half that. It isn't a small appliances, but it isn't all _that_ huge either. "If it happens, it must be possible." (My electric dryer circuit is 30A on each of its two legs...)

Comment: @Ecnerwal Nameplate voltage is 208-230, Amperate 25.5-24. It currently doesn't have a plug on it, just a flex conduit coming out of the magnetic starter enclosure.

Comment: There are higher-amperage connectors, though they may not be available in your local store. See, for example, https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Industrial_and_multiphase_power_plugs_and_sockets

Comment: Keshlam - 100% efficient motors don't exist, and even one of those would have to start - your currents are optimistic, and current is not the same as rated motor load anyway. Hubble (makers of Twist-Lock connectors) do list 5 HP connectors, but only in 480V, or 240V 3-phase. While a 50A range plug might work, it would not be up to code (only rated for 2 hp.) John Hodge - yes, that looks like a real 5 HP motor, at a glance. Having lived through the era when 120Volt 15 amp compressors were marketed as 5 and 6 (utterly fictional) horsepower, I had to ask.

Comment: @keshlam, not to sound rude, but your comment about not being able to take the compressor if it's hard wired is simply absurd. Even if it's in place when showing the house it would just be noted that it's not part of the sale. Same goes for lighting fixtures. Several times I have removed thousand dollar fixtures and replaced them with $2 keyless fixtures. As long as it's known up front.

Comment: That wasn't my comment. I just don't like hardwiring equipment that isn't actually "part of the house." It makes maintenance more difficult, and to my mind it's simply lazy. But de gustibus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was aware of four-inch extension rings but the ones I found attached in place of the mud ring. Fortunately someone pointed me to the existence of extension rings that attach to the mud ring. They're listed as attaching directly to a switch box.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure for a specfically "2-gang" box. These are made for 4" and 4-11/16 and octagon boxes:

[image: Box cover with knock-out - image from garvin industries]

and there are 1-gang "handy-box" covers with a knock-out as well.

A 4" box will take 2 devices, but some 4" boxes are set up with tabs for the devices, while others are set up with corner screws like this plate uses and need a cover to hold devices in place.

Comment: Thank you. I've seen covers like the one above, but my issue is as that I used 4" boxes with corner screws then attached a 3/4" mud ring using the corner screws to bring the front of the box flush with the surface of the drywall. What I need now is something to attach to the front of the mud ring (which has tabs for the devices) and will accept a conduit connector.

Comment: @JohnHodge:  That's what that knockout in the middle of the plate is for.  A conduit nipple goes through it.

Comment: @wallyk: Yes, but I need a plate that attaches to the mud ring using the device tabs and not directly to the box using the corner screws. The corner screws already have a mud ring attached to them and are now covered with drywall.

Comment: @JohnHodge:  What is the mud ring for?

Comment: @wally Bringing the front of the box flush with the drywall.

Comment: John you can replace the mud ring with an extension that will then allow you to add the cover with the conduit hole in the middle